# MySql Query example using Aggregate function

Tags: mysql

Doing some practice example queries in MySQL and I am stuck on one.

Here is the relevant table:

```
create table instructor (
    ID          varchar(5),
    name        varchar(20) not null,
    dept_name   varchar(20),
    salary      numeric(8,2) check (salary > 29000),
    primary key (ID),
    foreign key (dept_name) references department(dept_name)
        on delete set null
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

The question is: for each instructor, get their name, their salary and the number of instructors who earn more than they do.

Naturally, my mind goes to using the COUNT() aggregate function. I have come up with this answer (I know I added the ID column but it doesn't matter):

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.ID, T.name, T.salary, COUNT(S.ID) AS num
FROM instructor AS T, instructor AS S
WHERE S.salary>T.salary
GROUP BY T.ID;
```

But the issue here is that it leaves out the row for the instructor who earns the highest salary, as he is excluded in the WHERE clause.

I thought about making the WHERE clause greater than OR equal to and just decrementing each number but is that even possible?

I also thought that something like this would work:

```
Select DISTINCT T.ID, T.name, T.salary, S.salary as salary2, count(S.salary) as num
FROM instructor as T, instructor as S
WHERE S.salary>T.salary
group by T.ID
having S.salary>T.salary;
```

I've gotta be missing something easy here.

Comment: `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` together make no sense, also you have fallen for the bad MySQL habit of leaving out some non-aggregated columns from the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery instead.  It will also obviate the `GROUP BY`, etc.

```
Select  T.ID, T.name, T.salary, T.salary,
        ( SELECT count(*)
               FROM instructor AS S 
               WHERE S.salary > T.salary
        ) as num
    FROM  instructor as T;
```

Note

`COUNT(*)` is the usual way to say it; `COUNT(X)` counts how many Xs are not-NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following set of data:

[image]

```sql
SELECT ins.id, ins.name, ins2.id AS earns_more_emp_id, ins2.name AS earns_more_emp_name, ins2.salary AS earns_more_emp_salary 
FROM instructors ins
LEFT OUTER JOIN instructors ins2 on ins2.salary > ins.salary
ORDER BY ins.id ASC, ins2.salary ASC
```

That will give you the highest earner (EMP 10).

[image]

Comment: Please add context as to why your answer is the correct answer or adds value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using window functions, **without joining** and only scanning the base table once

```
SELECT
  i.ID,
  i.name,
  i.salary,
  COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY i.salary DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) - 1 AS earns_more
FROM instructor i;
```

You could also do this with a slightly different window frame, but I think this is less efficient

```
COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY i.salary DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS earns_more
```